# JasperReport- best approach for multiple pages static reports

Tags: java, jasper-reports

i need to create a static report of 3 pages and every page contains static text and fields retrieved with a database query.

My first approach, after reading similar questions, was to create 3 separated report files (page1.jrxml, page2.jrxml and page3.jrxml) and then merge the resulting reports into a single one. 
It works fine but sometimes happens that a field contains a very long string and a single file report generetes 2 pages, leading to an horrible printing because the first page is full but
the second contains one or few lines.

Can you suggest me a better approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use jrxml templates and we have only one jrxml. You do not need to have multiple files just split the static text to many DETAILS (paragraphs) and if the first page will overlap with few lines it will be inmediatelly followed by next detail.

In our app we use jasper from java and we pass the params with JasperFillManager.

We create template:

```
compiledTemplate = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(...);
```

and then we fill the variables

```
jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(compiledTemplate, map with params, dto implementing JRDataSource);
```

and then we export it to pdf:

```
ret = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrint);
```

and thats it.

Comment: What happens if a single JRXML contains 2 DETAILs and the first one, after filling, exceeds the size of an A4 page for few lines? Does the second page contain only the few lines?

Comment: I removed the recommendation with details. You can use even one detail. This is not important to have multiple details

Comment: I cannot use one detail because i haven't enough space...i must produce a 3-pages report (A4 format) with almost static text

Comment: I now see the problem. One solution would be to split the static text to many details (by paragraphs maybe). Then when the first page would overlap the first page with few lines it will be followed with next detail. Would this be the solution you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I've needed to split a report over several sheets primarily for Excel-export. It seems to be working while previewing on JasperServer also:

- add report property **net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.one.page.per.sheet** set to **true**
- add property **net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.after.row** set to **true** the the textfield you need a page break after (there's a similar one to break before)

Also you may name your sheets. Please see here:
http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.one.page.per.sheet